# Magento Extension Problems

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, install

Can anybody tell me that how can I remove all the settings associated to the extension from the database tables. Like if I am uninstalling the "abc" extension than the value `abc_setup` will also be deleted from the `core_resource` table. Similarly other setting from the `core_config_data` table too. And also delete the database tables too.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to do this manually. So find the record in `core_resource`, use the `system.xml` to find all the records via the `path` column in `core_config_data` and check the installer files to see what tables were created so you can remove them.

Automating something like this is kind of tricky. Using PHPMyAdmin or some other database viewer would probably make it quite an easy task

Answer (score 0):

Manually removing a module can be as simple as removing the module files (skin, layout.xml, template, etc..), but it can get a little more complicated such as removing database tables, removing column from core magento tables, removing EAV attributes, deleting core_resource and core_config_data.

To figure out what need to be don't take a look at system.xml (if any) to see the possible  entries for the core_config_data. Then take a look at the setup script folder (if any) and review each version to see what alteration was make to the database / magento

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete manually by first look system.xml and sql setup files. because all tables are created from sql setup file. If there is no uninstall script files then you must delete tables manually which are created by sql setup files.